# Signing into slack-desktop not working on 4.23.0 64-bit (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, authentication, slack, kde-plasma

In the app, going *File > Workspace > Sign in to new workspace* launches a browser window. After selecting the workspace in browser, it launches back a deep link back to slack but it doesn't work. Nothing happens on the slack-desktop.

When inspecting the commands being run during the linking process it looks like KDE is modifying the link. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: In my case it was something stupid: I had **http_proxy** configured, but no proxy running. So Slack couldn't connect, without any explanation, but Chrome ignores http_proxy, so it appeared to work fine.

Comment: The simplest solution I've found is going to this url:
https://[yourworkspace].slack.com/ssb/signin_redirect/fallback
There you can copy a magic link that the Slack desktop application will read from clipboard when you switch to it. I sometimes have to give it a couple tries, but it has always worked eventually :)

Comment: @aweibell, This worked for me thank you. However now every time I launch chrome, that page always launches. I checked Chrome settings and went to On Startup, and it is set to just open the new tab page. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @aweibell 's solution didn't work for me at first because I was using a tracker block (Vivaldi browser). I had to turn that off and then it worked.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

*The [answer provided by Boon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70867065/18169227) is correct. I wanted to leave comment under that answer but apparently I need 50 points to comment so I can only add new answer...*

After digging into the matter it sounds like the kde-open5 from kde-cli-tools is doing some funky lower-casing on first element of URL (`slack://A/B/C` becomes `slack://a/B/C`). This sounds like an old bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=429408

I suspect that slack changed in how they handle the links/links has changed - it aligns with slack upgrade in my case: slack-desktop:amd64 from 4.22.0 to 4.23.0.

Looking at process list:

- the slack website asks browser to open link with upper case
- kde-open5 is run with correct link
- slack is run with lower-cased workspace

I've reported this to slack with all the details so I hope it will be fixed.

### Workaround:

*Just adding some details to what ([Boon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70867065/18169227))*

1. Run the quick script in bash:

```
while sleep .1; do ps aux | grep slack | grep -v grep | grep magic; done
```

2. Try logging in to slack - accept login attempt in browser
3. You should see login link in console:

```
kde-open5 slack://WORKSPACE_ID/magic-login/...
/usr/lib/slack/slack --enable-crashpad slack://workspace_id/magic-login/...
```

4. Open the slack with correct link:

```
/usr/lib/slack/slack --enable-crashpad slack://WORKSPACE_ID/magic-login/...
```

Comment: thx. I added a comment in the KDE bug tracker: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=429408#c3

Comment: In some linuxes /usr/lib/slack/slack is just /usr/bin/slack

Comment: `/snap/bin/slack` for Slack installed from snap store

Comment: In my case, I was using Firefox and got it working after selecting the Slack app directly as the application to open Slack links - I guess, that goes around kde-open5 and thus solves it as well

Comment: The only viable workaround does actually involve some shell programming, so the question IS appropriate for StackOverflow after all.

Comment: And if you see the URL in the web browser, you can see the salck id, so you can copy and paste on the magic-login, and is the same, if you couldn-t find the uppercase url.

Comment: Note all you need to do is select the magic link and copy it to your clipboard. When you swap to slack, it will then automatically log in.

Comment: My solution on KDE was to switch default browser to firefox. The problem only occurs with chromium.

Comment: So poking around the source code - the host part of the slack:// url is being lower-cased as per https://code.woboq.org/kde/qt4/src/corelib/io/qurl.cpp.html#179 RFC 3491. So this is really a bug I think in slack, they should not use the host part of the url for a case-sensitve ID.

Comment: Thanks alot, I tried so many solutions but this one worked

Comment: I've been using Slack in my browser for weeks. I hate it. This worked!!!!

Comment: id like to add that it doesnt work for snap slack

Comment: This worked before, now does not work anymore. this is the what works now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867064/signing-into-slack-desktop-not-working-on-4-23-0-64-bit-ubuntu/71409129#71409129

Comment: To get slack URI you can just `journalctl --since today -f | grep -i slack://`. Then upcase workspace and `/bin/env slack slack://WORKSPACE_ID/magic-login/...`. No need in crashpad or hardcode slack path

Comment: The workaround worked for me on Kubuntu 22.04 with Slack 4.35.131. Thank you!

Comment: Somehow this has gotten even worse in Plasma 6. Now the first segment of the link is ALL lowercase, not just the first character.

Answer (score 122):

I'm using Archlinux, and neither clicking on link didn't work, neither passing link to slack arguments. Also you can find a correct link if you open dev console in browser it should be in console output. If you copy this link to your clipboard (ctrl+c) and then you switch to your slack app. It seems like onFocus slack automatically reads the clipboard and process it if it's a link. That gets be logged in.
[image]

Comment: It worked on Kubuntu 21.10, you saved me !!

Comment: Thanks! This is the easiest thing that worked!

Comment: Worked for me just now, Kubuntu 22.04, I tried all the rest suggested here, nothing worked for me but this.

Comment: Works for me Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma 5.24

Comment: Worked for me using Garuda Linux running Plasma 5.24.5

Comment: It worked on Fedora Workstation 36 running Plasma 5.25.4, used Chrome and Slack 4.28.171 installed from the official RPM from the website. Needed not just to "copy" the link, but to actually ensure it is inside the clipboard by pasting it somewhere first.

Comment: Worked for me too on Kubuntu 23.04 Thanks! :)

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer! It works for me as well

Comment: Still work on endeavour os in 2023

Comment: The only answer that helped me, thanks!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Such an easy workaround. This works for me.

Comment: Still only one working solution in 2023

Comment: nice hack, thank you!

Comment: Working for me on Kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 46):

Thanks to the excellent analysis of the issue here, I managed to create a script that saves me from this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "${1:-}" = slack://* ]]; then
    exec /usr/lib/slack/slack --enable-crashpad "$1"
fi

exec /usr/bin/xdg-open "$@"
```

Save the above script as `/usr/local/bin/xdg-open` and make the script executable. That's it!

I really hope the KDE team shows some love for such a fundamental issue, especially considering how widely used Slack is.

Comment: In some linuxes /usr/lib/slack/slack is just /usr/bin/slack

Comment: Clever! Much more refined solution than polling `ps` output. Verified on base Kubuntu 22.04. As noted, you'll need to use the `/usr/bin` prefix if you installed via official `.deb` package from slack.com

Comment: @trulyliu I am not sure where to add that snippet of code. The solution above would do everything for you. It overrides the system-wide `xdg-open`, just for slack. All you have to make sure is the paths for `slack` and the original `xdg-open` are correct. I didn't want to mess about with the string because I was uncertain whether it would be mixed case or not.

Comment: Great approach, saved me!, thanks so much

Comment: I used:
exec $(which slack) --enable-crashpad "$1"

Comment: This fixed the error for me on Arch / Manjaro Linux. This should be marked as the right answer!

Comment: Great approach. Works on `6.8.1-arch1-1`. However, I am disappointed that we still need this for a app like slack to work.

Answer (score 21):

Faced the same problem in Kubuntu 20.04 and the Chrome browser. Firefox solved this issue)

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that this worked for me using Kubuntu 22.04 and the snap Slack package! I tried the solutions in the other comments, but couldn't get them to work for me.

Comment: can confirm, firefox worked for me instead of chrome! thanks and cheers

Comment: Kubuntu 22.04, and yup, it indeed worked!

Comment: Simply setting Firefox as my default browser and using it to sign in (instead of Google Chrome) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me.  I did not even set as default browser.  I just copied and pasted the login URL into firefox and it forwarded and logged me into the desktop app.

Answer (score 15):

After trying various things, I noticed that what I suspect to be the workspace id, `tlvs8sasf` above are often in CAPS in the logs.

So, I tried updating the deep link by upper casing the workspace id, then click on it. Voila, it worked for me. Hope this helps anyone else also suffering from this same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I have this problem almost every time I restart my computer, and I have some 10 active slack workspaces, so hacked a quick bash script to do the caps trick for me. It's not meant to be robust, but it works. I'll leave it here in case it's useful for anybody else.

```
# Workaround to get slack to open workspaces correctly.
# Problem and workarond concept as described here:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867064/signing-into-slack-desktop-not-working-on-4-23-0-64-bit-ubuntu
# Usage: Run this script, open slack as normal, and attempt to log into workspaces as normal. Once done, kill the script.

while sleep .1; do 
        line=$(ps ax | grep slack | grep -v grep | grep magic | awk '{ print $NF }')
        WD=$(echo $line | cut -d '/' -f 3 | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
        LN=$(echo $line | cut -d '/' -f 5)
        if [ "$WD" != "" ]; then
                echo "got $line"
                line2="slack://$WD/magic-login/$LN"
                echo "Attempting to open $line2"
                /usr/lib/slack/slack --enable-crashpad $line2
        fi
done | grep -v "^$"
```